# GAE Go user service login url contains %A(MISSING)

Tags: google-app-engine, go

So this one's been puzzling me for a little while!

Here's some code in the console:

```
 func GetLoginLinks(w *http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (string, error) {
    c := appengine.NewContext(r)
    u := user.Current(c)
    if u == nil {
        url, err := user.LoginURL(c, r.URL.String())
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(*w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return "", err
        }

        c.Debugf("Return url: " + r.URL.String())
        c.Debugf("login url: " + url)
        c.Debugf("url type: %T", url)
        v := LoginItem(url, "Login")
        return v, nil
    }
 }
```

It gives the following output:

```
2013/06/17 21:48:28 DEBUG: Return url: /
2013/06/17 21:48:28 DEBUG: login url: /_ah/login?continue=http%A(MISSING)//localhost%A(MISSING)8080/
2013/06/17 21:48:28 DEBUG: url type: string
```

This also fails when uploaded to the app engine itself.

What I'm struggling with is the first 4 lines of the function comes directly from the developer guide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [package fmt](http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/)
>
> Format errors:
>
> If an invalid argument is given for a verb, such as providing a string
>   to `%d`, the generated string will contain a description of the problem,
>   as in these examples:
>
> ```
> Wrong type or unknown verb: %!verb(type=value)
>   Printf("%d", hi):          %!d(string=hi)
> Too many arguments: %!(EXTRA type=value)
>   Printf("hi", "guys"):      hi%!(EXTRA string=guys)
> Too few arguments: %!verb(MISSING)
>   Printf("hi%d"):            hi %!d(MISSING)
> Non-int for width or precision: %!(BADWIDTH) or %!(BADPREC)
>   Printf("%*s", 4.5, "hi"):  %!(BADWIDTH)hi
>   Printf("%.*s", 4.5, "hi"): %!(BADPREC)hi
> ```
>
> All errors begin with the string `"%!"` followed sometimes by a single
>   character (the verb) and end with a parenthesized description.
>
> If an `Error` or `String` method triggers a `panic` when called by a
>   print routine, the `fmt` package reformats the error message from the
>   panic, decorating it with an indication that it came through the `fmt`
>   package. For example, if a `String` method calls `panic("bad")`, the
>   resulting formatted message will look like
>
> ```
> %s(PANIC=bad)
> ```
>
> The `%s` just shows the print verb in use when the failure occurred.

You have an invalid format string. You have an escaped URL query string in a format string: "`:`" is escaped to "`%3A`". The format arguments for the "`%3A`" verbs are missing. For safety, never use an arbitrary string as a format string. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    url := "/_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/"
    fmt.Printf("login url: " + url)
    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Printf("login url: %s", url)
    fmt.Println()
}
```

Output:

```
login url: /_ah/login?continue=http%A(MISSING)//localhost%A(MISSING)8080/
login url: /_ah/login?continue=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/
```

Write:

```
c.Debugf("login url: %s", url)
```

Comment: That was just the ticket! It was also compounded by simply writing the  HTML generated elsewhere with `fmt.Fprintf(w, page_html)` rather than `fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s", page_html)`.

Watch out people.

Comment: Oh wow that was exactly what happened with my code when using Fprintf.  You should just use Fprint vs Fprintf to solve.  ex:   fmt.Fprint(w, page_html)